# How do I get AWS Amplify to automatically detect a Hugo Server project?

Tags: aws-amplify, hugo

I am attempting to use the directions at https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-aws-amplify/ to host a Hugo Site.

I've created the repository and am creating a new Amplify application. However, where the directions say that the Hugo framework should be auto detected it is not and I don't see a way to specify it manually. How does Amplify detect Hugo? What is the MVP for a Hugo server? It works fine locally.

The directory layout looks like this:

```
README.md
public
public/favicon.ico
public/index.html
public/posts
public/posts/index.xml
public/css
public/js
layouts
static
data
themes
```

Comment: What's your directory layout?

Comment: revised the question to include that info

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have the compiled pages, i.e. the final output there. One of the points of using a static site generator is that you can just version control your sources (your Markdown content), and then the site is generated when you need it.

The minimum setup you need to build a Hugo site is

```
.
├── config.toml
├── content
│   ├── about.md
├── layouts
```

or, if you're using a separate theme, add in the `themes/theme-name` directory.

I don't know how Amplify detects the types of projects, but most likely it tries guessing, based on the existence of some files in the directory, in this case `config.toml`, I suppose.

Comment: correct, public contains the generated data while the templates are in the theme folder

Comment: The point was to try adding the `content` directory and a `config.toml`. Does that help?